# SQL Error or Missing Database Near THEN When Querying sqlite_master

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am attempting to retrieve column information from a table in a database, but I am first checking to ensure that table exists. Running the `SELECT`s individually works just fine, but when I attempt to combine them into the `IF` structure, I get the following error:

> SQL Error[1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "THEN": syntax error)

Here is my SQL:

```sql
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT
        [name]
    FROM
        [main].[sqlite_master]
    WHERE
        [type] = 'table'
    AND
        [name] = 'myTableName'
)

THEN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        PRAGMA_table_info('myTableName')
    WHERE
        [name] = 'myColumnName';
        
END;
```

I am assuming my issue is lack of database name, but I do not understand what database name to use. I tried using `main` in front of the `PRAGMA_table_info`, but I get the same error. I tried with and without brackets. I tried `[dbo]` as well.

I have tried searching for my answer, but I have failed hard. Other similar questions have had more obvious issues, such as missing a space while concatenating strings, forgetting to close the `IF`, etc.

In case it matters, I am using DBeaver 23.2.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763516/information-schema-columns-on-sqlite

Comment: `IF` ... `THEN` is not valid sqlite syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that all you need is

```
SELECT * FROM PRAGMA_table_info('myTableName') WHERE name = 'myColumnName';
```

The output would either be 1 row or no rows if either the table or the column did not exist.

> but I do not understand what database name to use

The error message informs you of 2 potential causes:-

1. SQL error, **or**
2. missing database

The issue is that there is no `IF .... THEN .... ELSE .... END` construct in SQLite, and thus the issue with the SQL when THEN is found. `IF EXISTS` is a specific use case.

The equivalent of the `IF .... THEN .... ELSE .... END` construct is the `CASE .... WHEN .... THEN .... ELSE .... END` construct; see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression

However, the construct is used within an expression which equates to a single value (which for `IN` may be a list of values).

You actually want multiple values (all the columns or as you put it *column information*), hence the suggested.

As a demonstration, that shows two examples of `CASE....` construct, where;

1. The table and column exists, and
2. where the table does not exist  and the result is 'OOOPS'

And finally a few examples (via UNIONs) of the suggested straight forward suggested query:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x (c1 'whatever', c2 'blah');
/* Example utilising CASE.... construct where table and column found */
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM [main].sqlite_master WHERE [type] = 'table' AND name = 'x'
        )
            THEN (SELECT [name]   FROM PRAGMA_table_info('x') WHERE [name] = 'c1')
        ELSE 'OOOPS'
    END
;
/* Same example BUT for a rouge table i.e. works but returns OOOPS */
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM [main].sqlite_master WHERE [type] = 'table' AND name = 'y'
        )
            THEN (SELECT [name]   FROM PRAGMA_table_info('y') WHERE [name] = 'c1')
        ELSE 'OOOPS'
    END
;
/* Multiple unioned suggested */
SELECT
    /* 1. table and column exists = ALL GOOD */
    'attempt1',* FROM PRAGMA_table_info('x') WHERE name = 'c1' 
    /* 2. OUCH table z DOES NOT EXIST */
    UNION ALL SELECT 'attempt2',* FROM PRAGMA_table_info('z') WHERE name = 'obviously_not+a_name_as_table_does_not_exist'
    /* 3. table x does exists but OUCH column does not */
    UNION ALL SELECT 'attempt3',* FROM PRAGMA_table_info('x') WHERE name = 'obviously_not+a_name_as_table_does_not_exist'
    /* 4. OUCH table c1 does not exist*/
    UNION ALL SELECT 'attempt4',* FROM PRAGMA_table_info('c1') WHERE name LIKE '%2'
    /* 5. ALL GOOD table exists and so does a column c2 (column named abcdefghi2, if it existed would also match  LIKE ) */
    UNION ALL SELECT 'attempt5',* FROM PRAGMA_table_info('x') WHERE name LIKE '%2' AND type LIKE 'b%'
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
```

The first result (CASE WHEN) :-

[image]

- note only a single value can be extracted (returned from the expression SELECT * would result in `sub-select returns 6 columns - expected 1`)

The second result (CASE ELSE) :-

[image]

The third result:-

[image]

- noting that the UNIONs are purely to distinguish the attempts and results

So, as per the comments attempt 1 and 5 return a row each (which has the attempt added to indicate which returned a result). Attempts 2,3 and 4 returned nothing. Hence just the tow rows of output (in your case you would expect 1 or no rows).

- Note that the type IS NOT the type affinity of the column but the actual type as per the column's definition (hence the types defined as `whatever` and `blah`)